# The term "py" is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable ... path is correct and try again

Tags: python, sys

This code I can run in `Replit` but can't run in VSC. I have already checked PATH, but I can run from `RUN&DEBUG` but still can't run from the terminal. What should I do?

run & debug has not shown any problems.

Thank you for answering this question.

[image]

Comment: That should probably be `python contract.py` or `python3 contract.py`

Comment: Does Powershell keep a separate PATH? Is the script executable?

Answer (score 0):

A python file isn't an executable such as an .exe file.
To run a python script you need to run the `python` or `python3` command followed with the path to your script (`python contract.py`).

if both commands don't work you need to [add python to path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bUOrMj88Pc)

after that everything should work!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another c executable thing, What I did was to change permissions in the whole folder the files I want to execute are in (and I found out after searching--not my idea )
Here is the command for cmd
C:\Users\Lenovo>icacls "C:\pli10*" /grant administrators:F
the command to copypaste
icacls "C:\pli10*" /grant administrators:F
you change C:\pli10\ with your file path. (the file were the executable file is in.
Hope it helped.